# How to get all current supported php versions as json or xml?

Tags: php, json, xml, api

I would like to display dynamically in an application all current supported php versions to avoid hard code.
Is there an api, tool or link to do that?
I found [this](https://www.php.net/releases/?json) for last releases by version but I did not find for supported php versions like on this [page](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).
The best format should be json (xml eventually).
Someone has got this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for php.net is [available on Github](https://github.com/php/web-php/).

Browsing that, I found that a function called `get_active_branches` is used to generate the `supported-versions.php` page, and looking for other uses, I found this URL, which outputs it as JSON:

https://www.php.net/releases/active

Comment: I have found this project and fund this function. You are faster than me. Thanks a lot !